# motion elements under AnimatePresence not playing exit animation before being removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm having trouble using the [framer-motion-animate-presence component](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/)

I'm trying to create a menu navigation system that has sub menus that slide back and forth when they enter or exit but the menu you are currently on does not do its exit animation even though its just the same as the enter animation, I have set up unique keys and ids for all my menu pages so I don't understand why Animate Presence is instantly removing the menu that you navigate from instead of waiting for its animation to finish then removing it.

[link to a video displaying the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBSpc.jpg)

**the relevant section of where the dropdown component is used:**

```
<Header sections={["Intro", "What I Do", "About Me"]}
    sectionLinks={["#intro", "#what-i-do", "#about-me"]}
    logo={ <h4>{"<dev> Finn"}</h4> }
    >
    <Button icon={ <BsTwitter/> } type="header" link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA&t=842s"/>
    <Button icon={ <FaDiscord/> } type="header"/>
    <Button icon={ <FiMenu/>    } type="header">
        <Dropdown key="dropdown"
            pages={[
                { 
                    name: "main",
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: "Menu",
                            textType: "title",
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Settings",
                            buttonType: "navigation",
                            icon: <RiSettings4Fill/>,
                            goToPage: "settings",
                            goToDirection: "right"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "settings",
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: "Settings",
                            textType: "bold",
                            buttonType: "navigation",
                            icon: <FaArrowLeft/>,
                            goToPage: "main",
                            goToDirection: "left"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Appearance",
                            toggleType: "theme",
                            icon: ["", "☀️"],
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Cool Mode",
                            toggleType: "toggle",
                            icon: ["", ""],
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]}/>
                </Button>
            </Header>
```

**The dropdown component:** - (the last return statement is where the issue is)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

import Button from "./Button";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";


function Dropdown(props) {

    const [[activePage, pageDirection], setActivePage] = useState(["main", null]);
    const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState(null);
    const dropDownPage = useRef()

    function calcHeight() {
        const height = dropDownPage.current.offsetHeight
        setMenuHeight(height)
    }


    function DropdownItem(subprops) {
        return (
            <> 
                <a className="dropdown__item" onClick={() => {
                    subprops.goToPage && setActivePage([subprops.goToPage, subprops.goToDirection])
                    console.log(activePage, pageDirection)
                }}>
                    {subprops.textType === "title" ?
                        <>
                            <span className="dropdown__title">{subprops.text}</span> 
                        </> :
                        <>
                            {subprops.buttonType === "navigation" ? 
                                <>
                                    <div className="dropdown__button-container">
                                        <Button icon={subprops.icon} type="dropdown"/>
                                    </div>
                                </> :
                                <>
                                    {subprops.buttonType === "link" ?
                                        <>
                                            <div className="dropdown__button-container">
                                                <Button icon={subprops.icon} type="dropdown"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </> :
                                        <>  
                                            {subprops.toggleType === "theme" ?
                                                <>
                                                    <div className="dropdown__toggle-container">
                                                        <Toggle icons={subprops.icon} type="theme"/>
                                                    </div> 
                                                </> :
                                                <>
                                                    <div className="dropdown__toggle-container">
                                                        <Toggle icons={subprops.icon} type="toggle"/>
                                                    </div> 
                                                </>
                                            }
                                        </>
                                    }
                                </>
                            }
                            {subprops.textType === "bold" ?
                                <span className="dropdown__item__text-bold">{subprops.text}</span> :
                                <span className="dropdown__item__text">{subprops.text}</span>
                            }
                        </>
                    }
                </a>
            </>
        )
    }


    const dropdownVariants = {
        exit: {
            x: "150%",
            transition: { 
                type: "spring", 
                bounce: 0,
                damping: 15,
                mass: 1,
                stiffness: 50,
            }
        },
        enter: {
            x: 0,
            transition: { 
                type: "spring", 
                bounce: 0.3,
                damping: 15,
                mass: 1,
                stiffness: 100
            }
        }
    }


    const pageVariants = {
        enter: (pageDirection) => {
            return {
                x: pageDirection === "left" ? "-100%" : pageDirection === "right" ? "100%" : 0,
                transition: {
                    type: "spring", 
                    bounce: 0.3,
                    damping: 15,
                    mass: 1,
                    stiffness: 100
                }
            }
        },

        center: {
            x: 0,
            transition: {
                type: "spring", 
                bounce: 0.3,
                damping: 15,
                mass: 1,
                stiffness: 100
            }
        },

        exit: (pageDirection) => {
            return {
                x: pageDirection === "left" ? "-100%" : pageDirection === "right" ? "100%" : 0,
                transition: {
                    type: "spring", 
                    bounce: 0.3,
                    damping: 15,
                    mass: 1,
                    stiffness: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <motion.div className="header__dropdown" style={{ height: menuHeight}} key="header__dropdown"
            variants={dropdownVariants}
            initial="exit"
            animate="enter"
            exit="exit"
        >
            <AnimatePresence custom={pageDirection}>
                {props.pages.map((page) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment key={page["name"]}>
                            {activePage === page["name"] &&
                                <motion.div ref={dropDownPage} id={page["name"]} key={page["name"]}
                                    custom={pageDirection}
                                    variants={pageVariants}
                                    initial="enter"
                                    animate="center"
                                    exit="exit"
                                >

                                    {page["items"].map((item, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <DropdownItem key={index}
                                                text={item["text"]}
                                                textType={item["textType"]}
                                                link={item["link"]}
                                                buttonType={item["buttonType"]}
                                                toggleType={item["toggleType"]}
                                                icon={item["icon"]}
                                                goToPage={item["goToPage"]}
                                                goToDirection={item["goToDirection"]}
                                            />
                                        )
                                    })}

                                </motion.div>
                            }
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimatePresence` will animate its direct children when they are removed from the DOM. In your dropdown component, the direct children of `<AnimatePresence>` are `<React.Fragment>` elements that don't look like they are ever actually removed. Do you need those elements for some reason? If you remove them, and have the conditionally rendered `motion.div` elements as the children (with keys), it should work.

```
<AnimatePresence custom={pageDirection}>
    {props.pages.filter((p) => activePage === p["name"]).map((page) => {
        return (
                <motion.div ref={dropDownPage} id={page["name"]} key={page["name"]}
                    custom={pageDirection}
                    variants={pageVariants}
                    initial="enter"
                    animate="center"
                    exit="exit"
                >
                    {page["items"].map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <DropdownItem key={index}
                                text={item["text"]}
                                textType={item["textType"]}
                                link={item["link"]}
                                buttonType={item["buttonType"]}
                                toggleType={item["toggleType"]}
                                icon={item["icon"]}
                                goToPage={item["goToPage"]}
                                goToDirection={item["goToDirection"]}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </motion.div>
        )
    })}
</AnimatePresence>
```

I guess you were using fragments because you're mapping through the entire array of pages. I added a `filter` to reduce the array to just the items that should be rendered before calling `map`.

Comment: Omg your a legend I’ll try this out, yeah I was using fragments because it wouldn’t let me right that condition code straight after the return function.

Comment: this kinda works but I'm running into a new issue that can be viewed [here](https://imgur.com/a/FGcJ8LR) the entering page slides under the old page instead of sliding in behind it, this is exactly the look I want otherwise, just this one issue, any ideas?

Comment: You can probably just position them absolutely to the top of the container.